# How to show in GNU Screen hardstatus what tab was selected previously?

Tags: gnu-screen, screenrc

Every time I work in the console I use GNU Screen. I have a custom
.screenrc file with several settings. Among others I have the setting that
shows 'tabs' in the bottom:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%{= g} %{= w}%-w%{=r}%n %t%{-}%+W"
```

It works well, but I want to add to the tabs some symbol that shows what
tab was previously active. How can this be done?

Answer (score 6):

Alas, comments support only a bit of formatting abilities, so i created a new answer.

> 1) There is some '$' symbol after every tab number that are not needed

With `hardstatus string "%{= g} %{= w}%-Lw%{=r}%n%f* %t%{-}%+LW"` i can't see any '$':

[image]

> 2) the symbols '' and '-' make the tab one symbol wider and because of that the tabs jumps a little. I think it can be solved by placing space if there is no '' and '-' symbols.

Alas, all tabs besides selected are not configured - they are just shown if `%w` ( all windows including current ) or `%W` ( all windows except current ) are used in hardstatus string. These escapes can be prepended with `-` or `+` ( to show windows before or after current one ) and `L` ( to show window's flags ). Spaces, or formatting, or content of these parts of line can't be configured - they have only tab's number, title and optionally flags with fixed indents.

> 3) The symbol '*' is not needed because there is also a color selection of the current tab.

Sure, you can replace `*` with space after `%f` in hardstatus string with two spaces ( sorry for strange sentence, but SO text engine eats spaces in backticks weirdly ) - but without adjusting spaces after tab's number for non-active and non-last tabs they continue "to jump".

Comment: Thank you. =) It does not solve all my problems, but anyway thank you for such a detailed answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use can use following string:

```
hardstatus string "%{= g} %{= w}%-Lw%{=r}%n%f* %t%{-}%+LW"
```

Than window with focus will be marked with symbol '*' and previous one - with '-'.

Comment: Thank you! It is great but it does not exactly what I need. I tried to figure out myself how to fix it, but I failed. 1) There is some '$' symbol after every tab number that are not needed 2) the symbols '*' and '-' make the tab one symbol wider and because of that the tabs jumps a little. I think it can be solved by placing space if there is no '*' and '-' symbols. 3) The symbol '*' is not needed because there is also a color selection of the current tab.